# Make a data table using exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, exceljs

I'm trying to format some data into a Excel table, I already have the data written in the Excel file, but I want it as a table, is there any way to do this, if not, is there any way with another npm package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the range to table:

```
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
let expensesTable = sheet.tables.add("A1:E7", true);
expensesTable.name = "ExpensesTable";
```

here is the sample gist that you could have a try
https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/8eccb88f7fccf34b63c7ecd5fd05aaea

Comment: I get `context is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Tables allow for in-sheet manipulation of tabular data.](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#tables)

```
import * as exceljs from 'exceljs';

const workbook = new exceljs.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('William');

// add a table to a sheet
worksheet.addTable({
  name: 'Dam',
  ref: 'A1',
  headerRow: true,
  totalsRow: true,
  style: {
    theme: 'TableStyleDark3',
    showRowStripes: true,
  },
  columns: [
    {name: 'Date', totalsRowLabel: 'Totals:', filterButton: true},
    {name: 'Amount', totalsRowFunction: 'sum', filterButton: false},
  ],
  rows: [
    [new Date('2019-07-20'), 70.10],
    [new Date('2019-07-21'), 70.60],
    [new Date('2019-07-22'), 70.10],
  ],
});
```